# Marginal PDF for Extended Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a joint pdf that is a hyper-geometric distribution that is

$f(x,y)$ = $13 \choose x$ $26 \choose y$ $ 13 \choose 2 - x -y$ / $ 52 \choose 2$ for $ x+y \leq 2$, $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $0$ other wise.

I need to find the Marginal PDF's $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. By definition of Marginal PDF $f(x) = \sum_{y=0}^{2-x} f(x,y) $ = $13 \choose x$ / $ 52 \choose 2$ $\sum_{y=0}^{2-x}$$26 \choose y$ $ 13 \choose 2 - x -y$

I am not sure how to sum this, and I feel like I am not summing the right limits.

Also, I know that the Marginal PDF for the Extended Hyper-Geometric is the Univariate Hyper-Geometric, so for the problem above $f(x)$ = $13 \choose x$ $39 \choose 2-x$ / $ 52 \choose 2$ but how do I find this $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

We use a **Combinatorial Argument**.

$\binom{13}{x}\binom{26}{y}\binom{13}{2-x-y}$ counts the way to pick 2 cards from a deck such that those 2 cards consist of $x$ hearts, $y$ black (club or spade), and the remainder are diamond.

Summing this over all possible $y$, $0\leq y\leq 2-x$ would count the way to pick 2 cards from a deck such that we have $x$ hearts and $2-x$ from the $39$ non-heart cards.   This would be $\binom{13}{x}\binom{39}{2-x}$

That is all.

$$f_X(x)=\dfrac{\sum_{y=0}^{2-x}\binom{13}{x}\binom{26}{y}\binom{13}{2-x-y}}{\binom{52}{2}}= \dfrac{\binom{13}{x}\binom{39}{2-x}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$

---

In general $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \dbinom{n}{i}\dbinom{m}{k} = \dbinom{n+m}{k}$ by the same argument.   If we count all ways to select $i$ from a heap of $n$ items and $k-i$ from a heap of $m$ items, for all $i$ from $0$ to $k$, then we have counted ways to select $k$ items from both heaps combined.

Comment: Ok I see, but I thought maybe there was a summing relation for the counting techniques that I was not seeing.

Comment: Also, it is 13 choose x and 26 choose y and 13 choose 2 - x - y, so I am assuming the same process of counting holds.

Comment: Yes.  Either way.  $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i} = \binom{n+m}{k}$